# How to establish a gpib connection in matlab?

Tags: matlab

How can I send waveform to my keysight 33522b waveform generator ? I've searched many hours this topic but I couldn't find any helpful guide about gpib command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instrument control for lab equipment is done via drivers now specified by the [IVI foundation](http://www.ivifoundation.org/), which Keysight (Agilent) is signed up to. Control is implemented in [VISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Instrument_Software_Architecture) libraries. I believe the IVI/VISA thing is an attempt by instrument manufacturers to standardise and simplify communication with instruments.

If you are using Matlab, I would look into the [instrument control toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/index.html), which implements a VISA interface for Matlab and does a lot of the hard work for you. If you do not have access to the toolbox, you might have to manually call the VISA DLL routines that should have been installed when you installed your GPIB card on your computer.